Why am I getting a 404 page not found when using useRouter?
After the user submits a form, I want to redirect them to a thank you page. However, when the backend logic is processed, it redirects me to a 404 page. I checked the URL path and everything seems fine.
My project is structured like this: app -> pages -> ThankYou.tsx
Everything is happening in the FormFile.tsx which is located in the form directory inside of components.
(app -> components -> form -> FormFile.tsx )
Here is how things look:
***IMPORT STATEMENTS/ FORM SCHEMA AT THE TOP***


const FormFile = () => {   
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      numberOfKids: 0
    }   })   

    const router = useRouter();   

    const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      console.log(values);
      const response = await axios.post('/api/formInput', values)
      router.push('/ThankYou'); //This is supposed to redirect the user to ThankYou.tsx
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }   };

  return (
    <>
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit, (errors) => console.log(errors))}>
          {/* FIRST NAME */}
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="firstName"
...

Even when I enter this in the URL to test how ThankYou.tsx will look like, I get a 404...
http://localhost:3000/pages/ThankYou

Incase your wondering, this is what ThankYou.tsx looks like for now...
import React from 'react'

const ThankYou = () => {
  return (
    <div>ThankYou</div>
  )
}

export default ThankYou


Is the target URL path "/thankyou" or is it "/pages/thankyou"? I think "/pages/thankyou" returning a 404 page is correct though. Can you verify that "/thankyou" works if you manually navigate there?

yeah '/ThankYou' doesn't work.

I see. You should probably get that sorted out first so it's available to be navigated to. Can you [edit] to provide more details about your routing structure and where/how you are serving/hosting the app and how that is setup/configured? See [mcve].

Apologies for the late messages, you are a legend so sorry for the disrespect. I ended up solving the problem, for some reason when I changed the file name from ThankYou.tsx to page.tsx and updated router.push('/thankyou');  to router.push('/pages');, it worked. The content was rendered and everything magically worked. Very interesting, if you know why this happened I would love to know, thank you for the help though, changing the file names was where it was at.

Are you using app routing or pages routing? Typically with these you'd have an app directory and a pages directory for each. Based on what you describe it sounds like you are using the app routing, and had a page directory named pages within that, so renaming the file from ThankYou.tsx to page.tsx it fixed it I guess. page is part of the file conventions.

The ThankYou.tsx file name likely would work if you were using the pages directory and routing. You can use both at the same time from what I understand.

Also, I don't think you have anything to apologize for, I have no idea what disrespect you are referring to.

Yeah, it was app routing, didn't know the difference between the two. Anyone who helps developers when they are stuck is a legend in my book. I just felt like I was maybe wasting your time by not responding on time, thank you though fr.

Check your router-DOM, it is succesfully installed or not, also check version, if react-router-dom is good installed, then check api's and console the error, where issue presists. Would you mind sharing more details for better understanding about this error.

router-DOM is installed, the only error I see when I navigate to ThankYou.tsx is
GET http://localhost:3000/ThankYou 404 (Not Found)

Do you mean react-dom? What is router-DOM? OP is using Next.js which is a server-side-rendering library. React-Router-DOM is a client-side routing library. Chances are OP isn't using both, at least they haven't indicated they are trying to use both at the same time.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
